# Compare journey date with return date in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have to compare Journey date with return date. Return date should be Greater than equal to journey date. Which validator should be used for that & how?
Help me.
Asp.net c#.
Thank you.

Comment: could you please mention your date format, i mean is mm/dd/yy or some other format ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CustomValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.aspx) and check the validation in client-side or server-side

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="cvComment" runat="server" ClientValidationFunction="clientCheckDateTime"
    Enabled="true" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="[Control ID]" Text="[Your Message]" />


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 function clientCheckDateTime(source, arguments) {        
    arguments.IsValid = [Check Validation];
 }
 </script>
```